# Is there a simpler method to compute $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n } x\right)} d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

When I encountered the integral $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2 } x\right)} d x $, I tried the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}  $ and found a wonderful result.
$$I=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2 } x\right)} d x \stackrel{x\mapsto\frac{1}{x}}{=} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2 } x\right)} d x  $$
Averaging them yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^2 x\right)}+\frac{1}{x(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^2 x\right)}\right]dx\\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\left(\pi+\ln ^2 x\right)} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\pi+\ln ^2 x} d(\ln x) \\
& =\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\right)\right]_0^{\infty}\\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Then I want to **generalize** the result to the integral

$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n } x\right)} d x $$
By replacing the power $2$ by $2n$, we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x\left(\pi+\ln ^{2 n} x\right)} d x\\ &=  \frac{\sqrt[2 n]{\pi}}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^{2 n}} d x \quad (\textrm{ via } \ln x \mapsto \sqrt[2 n]{\pi} x)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the well-known result $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{1+x^n}=\frac{\pi}{n} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)$, we have
$$
I_n=\frac{\sqrt[2 n]{\pi}}{2 n} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{2 n}\right)
$$
For **simplicity**, given any even integer $m$, we have
$$
\boxed{\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{m } x\right)} d x =\frac{\sqrt[m]{\pi}}{m} \csc \left(\frac{\pi}{m}\right)}
$$

---

For examples,
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2 } x\right)} d x =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \\
& \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{4 } x\right)} d x =\frac{\sqrt[4]{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{2}} \\
& \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)\left(\pi+\ln ^{6 } x\right)} d x =\frac{\sqrt[6]{\pi}}{3}
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Are there any **other** methods?
Comments and alternative methods are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution. (+1)

Comment: Your appreciation supports me to do more investigations in future.  Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not the type to give compliments for nothing. During the last three years, I followed your questions and answers. You have a real talent. Cheers :-)

Comment: Hi Lai, could you tell me what you meant by averaging I and what is the motivation behind that. Great solution by the way...

Comment: It means to take the average of the two versions of the integral so as to cancel and hence get rid of the term (1+x) in the denominator.  Wish you understand!

Comment: Claude Leibovic, I always learn from you, your enthusiasm in math and  fast methods in tackling problems  with various perspectives.

Comment: It strikes me that the $\pi$ in the denominator is not relevant

Comment: Cleo shall be impressed.

Comment: I hope so very much!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general extension

$$I_n=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x(1+x^a)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n } x\right)}\ dx =\frac{\pi^{\frac1{2n}}}{2n\sin\frac\pi{2n}}$$

Comment: $I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{d x}{x^{2-a}\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n }x\right)}$ can’t be continued.  Am I right?

Comment: @Lai - You would have $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(1+x^a)\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n } x\right)} \overset{x\to \frac1x}= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x(1+x^{-a})\left(\pi+\ln ^{2n } x\right)}
$

Comment: Yes, you are right! I forgot that you added $x$ in the denominator in addition to $x^a$.  Thank you very much for your extension,